Can excited state Fukui functions be calculated?
Is it possible or valid to calculate the Fukui functions from LR-TDDFT?

The Fukui function is in a finite difference version calculated as the electron density difference between (typically) a neutral molecule and its cation/anion. There is no formal problem in using excited state densities for this. The Fukui function can be used to predict e.g. regioselectivity in reactions, but very few excited states have lifetimes long enough that intermolecular reactions can happen.
